# Dplyr "Arrange" function not working when passing arguments to it inside a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been looking around posts about passing arguments to dplyr functions inside a custom function, and I could not solve the following situation:

I have created the following function to get a subset of a dataframe.

```
library(Lahman)

top_leaders <- function(df, metric, n) {
     # metric is the name of the column of Batting df which I would like to analyze
     # n is the number of top players leaders on that metric

    stat_leader <- enquo(metric)

    df %>%
      dplyr::select(playerID, !!stat_leader) %>% 
      dplyr::top_n(n)
  }
```

As this function works well subsetting the n players leaders on that stat. For example:

```
> top_leaders(Lahman::Batting, "R", 5)
Selecting by R
   playerID   R
1 oneilti01 167
2 brownto01 177
3 hamilbi01 198
4  ruthba01 177
5 gehrilo01 167
```

Nevertheless, I want the result to be ordered, so I use include the `arrange` function to order it by the stat.

```
top_leaders <- function(df, metric, n) {
    stat_leader <- enquo(metric)

    df %>%
      dplyr::select(playerID, !!stat_leader) %>% 
      dplyr::top_n(n) %>%
      dplyr::arrange(desc(!!stat_leader))
  }
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Selecting by R
 Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 5
```

I tried later to use `arrange_(desc(!!stat_leader))` getting also another error:

```
Selecting by R
 Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.

  # Bad:
  list(!!myquosure)

  # Good:
  dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)
```

So I have no ideia on how to solve this.

Comment: Does it work when you call it with bare column names, i.e. `R` instead of `"R"`? That's the convention in these `dplyr`-based functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to convert to `sym`bol here as we are passing a string.

```
top_leaders <- function(df, metric, n) {
    stat_leader <- ensym(metric)

     df %>%
       dplyr::select(playerID, !!stat_leader) %>% 
       dplyr::top_n(n) %>%
       dplyr::arrange(desc(!!stat_leader))
     }
top_leaders(Lahman::Batting, "R", 5)
#Selecting by R
#   playerID   R
#1 hamilbi01 198
#2 brownto01 177
#3  ruthba01 177
#4 oneilti01 167
#5 gehrilo01 167
```

It would also work if we pass unquoted variable name

```
top_leaders(Lahman::Batting, R, 5)
#Selecting by R
#   playerID   R
#1 hamilbi01 198
#2 brownto01 177
#3  ruthba01 177
#4 oneilti01 167
#5 gehrilo01 167
```

---

With the OP's function, it expects unquoted argument only instead of quoted

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This also worked, and it's good to be flexible with the argument quoted or not,

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of [Rlang's new curly-curly notation](https://www.r-bloggers.com/curly-curly-the-successor-of-bang-bang/):

```
top_leaders <- function(df, playerID, metric, n) {
  df %>%
    dplyr::select({{playerID}}, {{metric}}) %>% 
    dplyr::top_n(n) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc({{metric}})) %>% 
    return(.)
}

top_leaders(as_tibble(Lahman::Batting), playerID, R, 5)

#Selecting by R
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  playerID      R
#  <chr>     <int>
#1 hamilbi01   198
#2 brownto01   177
#3 ruthba01    177
#4 oneilti01   167
#5 gehrilo01   167
```

You will need to pass playerID to the function, too, but that's a minor alteration.